# How to read this kanji?

Tags: kanji, handwriting, calligraphy

[image]

Please tell me how to read this kanji. What does it mean?

Comment: More generally, how does one read any kanji like this?

Answer (score 12):

It looks to me like [[舞]{まい}](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%88%9E) (dance)...

Comment: Confirmation can be found by looking at some samples from here: http://moji.tekkai.com/zoom/%E8%88%9E/page.html

Comment: Thanks :) By the way @snailboat had already found [this](https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/12047003_801246979983187_3484240230889904369_n.jpg?oh=75ce4c291cadad7e37bc127f6a7dde0a&oe=566960B5)! :D